# SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code in `tbody`

```
<tr v-for="item in apiResponse.costGroups" :key="item.process_receipt_id">
    <td class="pl-0 pr-0">
        <el-input type="text" v-model="getCostGroupProp(item, 'process_receipt_date')" class="no-border-input-datatable"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

in `methods` object, I have the following code.

```
methods: {
  getCostGroupProp(costGroup, prop) {
    return costGroup[prop]
  }
}
```

and I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue

However it is working just fine when I write HTML code like this.

```
<tr v-for="item in apiResponse.costGroups" :key="item.process_receipt_id">
    <td class="pl-0 pr-0">
        <el-input type="text" v-model="item.process_receipt_date" class="no-border-input-datatable"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have read in one of the questions on StackOverflow that the problem is we cannot have a number in the v-model. But, I don't have a number in the v-model & the code is also working fine with the second approach and with the same set of properties so I don't understand why.

Can anyone help me understand why it is so? I appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: `getCostGroupProp(item, 'process_receipt_date') = newInputValue` wouldn't be valid JavaScript, that's why you get this error.

Comment: @CherryDT interesting, I thought it would be returning the values as with the computed or data properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not assign v-model to a method. v-model is two way binding. Use a data property or computed property (with set/get methods).